# node script that runs both standard and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I'm trying to run both [JavaScript Standard Style](http://standardjs.com/index.html) and Mocha as a single task in my package.json scripts configuration, with a NODE_ENV of test so that mocha picks up my test.js config (i'm using the npm package `config`), but the standard part isn't running. In my package.json file I have the following script defined:

```
"test": "export NODE_ENV=test standard && mocha"
```

If i remove the NODE_ENV=test then it runs both standard and mocha, but the process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined, so mocha does not pick up my test config settings.

How do I have mocha run with 'test' NODE_ENV setting, and have 'standard' run before the tests?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need *export* just write it like this, and put NODE_ENV=test in front of both *standard* and *mocha*:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test standard && NODE_ENV=test mocha"
```

Comment: yeah i tried that to start with but if I console log process.env.NODE_ENV inside a test it is 'undefined'

Comment: how about NODE_ENV=test standard && NODE_ENV=test mocha

Comment: ahh... yes that worked...  if you update your answer I'll accept it. I'm actually changing it to "standard && NODE_ENV=test mocha" as i dont care what env is running for standard - thanks!!